# Linking Intel's MKL within Python-C++-C-Fortran 2003 program

Tags: c++, python, boost, fortran, intel-mkl

I am trying to link a program which nature is pretty complicated:

- developed and run under Linux Fedora
- main code written in fortran 2003 is heavily relies on Intel's MKL library and small pieces of ANSI C code
- it has C++ interface (use iso_c_binding)
- the c++ interface is accessed from python via boost.python

During the runtime I get the following text

```
MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load neither libmkl_avx.so nor libmkl_def.so
```

after which program stops.

I have checked that both `libmkl_avx.so` and `libmkl_def.so` are in `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

The final linking is done via:

```
g++ -g3 -shared -Wl,-soname,libFrrBoost_rt.so interfejs.o t83.o gen_random2.o 
-L/opt/intel/composerxe/mkl/lib/intel64 -lpython2.7 -lifport -lifcore -lboost_python     
-Wl,--start-group -lmkl_sequential -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core  -Wl,--end-group 
-o libFrrBoost_rt.so
```

libFrrBoost is the module that is linked, then

running `python t83.py` (in particular linker does not complain when preparing the binary file) which imports the module libFrrBoost causes the error.

Tried to google. All the info I found was connected with "usual programs" written in C/Fortran and simply including Intel's MKL. I am able to run this sort of programs with no problem. I think the MKL part of the linking line in the Makefile is equivalent in both cases, but there must be somewhere a hidden mystery. The problem was usually bad linking - which I do not see applicable (the libraries are exactly as in Intel's manual - Interface, Threading and computational libraries are pretty standard)

Used compilers:

ifort 12.1.0, icpc 12.1.0, python Python 2.7.1, icc 12.1.0 (the small C snippet also calls MKL, but)

**EDIT (due to a comment of Hirsto Iliev)**

I have run the strace in this way: `strace python t83.py`; The result is (after grepping `libmkl`:

```
open("/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_avx.so", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/usr/bin/libmkl_avx.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/slurm-2.2.5/lib/libmkl_avx.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/compiler/lib/intel64/libmkl_avx.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/debugger/lib/intel64/libmkl_avx.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_avx.so", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

I understand that the specification for open is as in [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Opening-and-Closing-Files.html) an, in particular, as 3,4 are positive and indicate that open has found a file and assigned it file discriptors. I have verified that the file does exist in that place.

also this is "good" Intel compiler directory as:

```
czeslaw@stefan:~/prog/FoCpy3 $ which ifort
/opt/intel/composer_xe_2011_sp1.7.256/bin/intel64/ifort
```

So the version is the same - aparently it is not a version issue.

Everything is the same for `libmkl_def.so`.

**DISCLAIMER**: Although I may sound confident in what I write I am not. Every sentence should begin with "If I am not mistaken".

Comment: Trace your program with `strace -f -e trace=file -o trace.out ./program args...` and then grep for `libmkl_def` in `trace.out` to see in what locations `dlopen()` actually looks for it.

Comment: Genial! I did not know this command. However the results are unsatisfactionary. I will edit the main post and answer there, as I require more space and more formatting option than comment.

Comment: Take some professional advice -- http://software.intel.com/sites/products/mkl/ -- has helped me out more than once

Comment: Thanks - I have just tried that. Unfortunately it generated the same linking line as I have used in the Makefile (the only difference: there was no `-Wl,--start-group` and `-Wl,--end-group` in it - which should not matter (and it does not - I have checked by recompilation) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the solution is to link with `-lmkl_rt` instead of `-lmkl_sequential -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core`. I do not see why one should give advantageous over te other. I am confused but that works (so far).

**edit**
Intel people claim this was MKL library bug.

Comment: mkl_rt is a wrapper library that dlopens the proper mkl_whatever for your platform. You should always link against mkl_rt, not the specific mkl_whatever.

Comment: I saw lots of related questions/answers but this answer is only one which solves this problem.

Answer (score 11):

For me solution proposed on the [intel site](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/300857) works well

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so:/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.so
```

It seem to be some kind of bug.

Comment: +1, also worked for me when I found this bug using intel compiled python numpy/scipy built against mkl library.

Comment: `locate mkl` will show you your location, if it was not installed in the default location

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was building something that in the `.configure` script does not link against `mkl_rt`. This saves the day!